# Map the Advance Seach webpart to use "osssearchresults.aspx" as the Result URL instead of "Results.aspx"

Tags: 2013, web-part, search, enterprise-search, advanced-search

I want to add an Advance Search Page to my live site collection inside sharepoint 2013.but on our live web application , i did not create an Enterprise Search Center site collection. so i did the following steps:-

1. Inside our test sharepoint, i added a new site collection of type "Enterprise Search Center".
2. I navigate to "Site content">>"Pages">>"`Advance.aspx`".
3. edit the "`Advance.aspx`" page , export the related web part.save it my PC.
4. then on live sharepoint environment. i uploaded the exported web part from "Site setting2>>"Web Parts".
5. after that i modify the home page for our live site collection.
6. add the uploaded web part.
7. so now i got the advance search web part inside my live site collection, without the need to create the Enterprise Search Center site collection.as follow:-

[image]

8. now by default the advance search web part on live will redirect to `results.aspx` which does not exists on live site collection.
9. so on the live web part, i edit the web part change the Result URL from `results.aspx` to  `osssearchresults.aspx`.as follow

[image]

10. i did a test and seems everything is working well.

but i am not sure if the above steps are valid ? i mean i am using the Advance Search capabilities on live , without creating a dedicated Enterprise Search Center site collection??
Thanks

Comment: I can't think of any reason as to why it wouldn't work. You don't need the search centre.

Comment: @Bunzab thanks for the reply... so you mean i can use this web part inside my live site collection even if i do not create a dedicated enterprise search center site collection + i can modify the Results URL ?? i also found my steps valid,, but i was afraid of behind the senses issues??

Comment: Yes. The search center just gives you the convenience of having all web parts pre-rolled into pages. It does have a benefit of being independent of the rest of the platform and can scale. If none of that impacts you then you're fine.